# NativeCrypto - AppData create pipe(2) failed Too many open files

Tags: c#, android

I am facing one issue with android version above 5.0, whenever i am doing foreground and background for the application its getting crash. I am not sure the same code base is working android lowest version. Is there any limitation functionality for lollipop?. Please find following error log information,

AndroidRuntime Shutting down VM

> NativeCrypto AppData - create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files
>
> NativeCrypto AppData - create pipe(2) failed: Too many open files

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from some of the experiment from my end and xamarin forum as well. Actually, we have one class like getting and creating connection in sqlite. However we are not closing the connection on subsequent request to proceed further. Thanks.